# Symfony first page - The autoloader expected class […] to be defined in file

Tags: php, symfony

I have checked similar issues but posted by others but I still cannot see what is wrong in my code.

I just copied it from the documentation - https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/page_creation.html

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class LuckyController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number")
     */
    public function numberAction()
    {
        $number = mt_rand(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

> The autoloader expected class "App\Controller\LuckyController" to be
>   defined in file "E:\projektai\php
>   projektai\htdocs\mokomieji\weather_demo_3\vendor\composer/../../src\Controller\LuckyController.php".
>   The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or
>   namespace probably has a typo in E:\projektai\php
>   projektai\htdocs\mokomieji\weather_demo_3\config/services.yaml (which
>   is loaded in resource "E:\projektai\php
>   projektai\htdocs\mokomieji\weather_demo_3\config/services.yaml").

So it says file was found but the class was not found. How can class be not found? I see it. How does it try to search for it?

composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.0.8",
        "symfony/console": "^3.4",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/lts": "^3",
        "symfony/yaml": "^3.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/dotenv": "^3.4"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install --symlink --relative %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "id": "01C16444CCZTY1MPPEE5GJZ63G",
            "allow-contrib": false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on that structure you are probably using Symfony Flex, so your namespace should be `namespace App\Controller;`

try switching to [4.0 version of documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html).

Comment: I do not think I am using symfony flex, at least I do not know what is that. Will add composer.json after writhe the comment.

My task is to use symfony 3, so using symfony 3 docs should be good.

Comment: @Darius.V you are using symfony flex, check your composer dependencies, just follow documentation for Symfony 4 and namespace is now `App`. Also Symfony 3.4 = Symfony 4

Comment: No, Symfony 3.4 is not equal to Symfony 4, as in v4, all deprecated features are removed

Comment: @NicoHaase true, I just wanted to tell him that he can use the documentation of Symfony 4.0 as it is basically the same only without the deprecated features.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I hadn't used php in a while, I also copy/pasted from the tutorial, but I actually forgot to add

```
<?php
```

at the beginning of the file. Results in the same error message.

Comment: Another potential misstep is to forget running "composer install" before you start coding.